# "Add to WishList" and "BuyNow" buttons are missing | Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WordPress Woo-commerce website

- On the Product Catalogue Page - Both the Buttons "Buy Now" and **"Add to Wishlist"** are missing
- On the Single Product Page - "**Buy Now**" Button is missing.

In the Wordpress Admin i found a PHP for wishlist, is there anything wrong in this code that this has disabled the button "Add to wishlist" ? how to enable "Add to wishlist" button ?

```
<?php
/**
 * Wishlist page template
 *
 * @author Your Inspiration Themes
 * @package YITH WooCommerce Wishlist
 * @version 1.0.0
 */

global $wpdb, $yith_wcwl, $woocommerce;

if( isset( $_GET['user_id'] ) && !empty( $_GET['user_id'] ) ) {
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
} elseif( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
}

$current_page = 1;
$limit_sql = '';

if( $pagination == 'yes' ) {
    $count = array();

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $count = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(*) as `cnt` FROM `' . YITH_WCWL_TABLE . '` WHERE `user_id` = %d', $user_id  ), ARRAY_A );
        $count = $count[0]['cnt'];
    } elseif( yith_usecookies() ) {
        $count[0]['cnt'] = count( yith_getcookie( 'yith_wcwl_products' ) );
    } else {
        $count[0]['cnt'] = count( $_SESSION['yith_wcwl_products'] );
    }

    $total_pages = $count/$per_page;
    if( $total_pages > 1 ) {
        $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'page' ) );

        $page_links = paginate_links( array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link( 1 ) . '%_%',
            'format' => '&page=%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'show_all' => true
        ) );
    }

    $limit_sql = "LIMIT " . ( $current_page - 1 ) * 1 . ',' . $per_page;
}

if( is_user_logged_in() )
    { $wishlist = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `" . YITH_WCWL_TABLE . "` WHERE `user_id` = %s" . $limit_sql, $user_id ), ARRAY_A ); }
elseif( yith_usecookies() )
    { $wishlist = yith_getcookie( 'yith_wcwl_products' ); }
else
    { $wishlist = isset( $_SESSION['yith_wcwl_products'] ) ? $_SESSION['yith_wcwl_products'] : array(); }

// Start wishlist page printing
$woocommerce->show_messages() ?>
<div id="yith-wcwl-messages"></div>

<form id="yith-wcwl-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( $yith_wcwl->get_wishlist_url() ) ?>" method="post">
    <?php
    do_action( 'yith_wcwl_before_wishlist_title' );

    $wishlist_title = get_option( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_title' );
    if( !empty( $wishlist_title ) )
        { echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_wishlist_title', '<h2>' . $wishlist_title . '</h2>' ); }

    do_action( 'yith_wcwl_before_wishlist' );
    ?>
    <table class="shop_table cart wishlist_table" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="product-thumbnail"><?php _e( 'Image', 'Maxshop' ) ?></th>
                <th class="product-name"><?php _e( 'Product Name', 'Maxshop' ) ?></th>
                <th class="product-price"><?php _e( 'Unit Price', 'Maxshop' ) ?></th>
                <th><?php _e( 'Stock Status', 'Maxshop' ) ?></th>
                <th><?php _e( 'Action', 'Maxshop' ) ?></th>
                <th class="product-remove"><?php _e( 'Remove', 'Maxshop' ) ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php            
            if( count( $wishlist ) > 0 ) :
                foreach( $wishlist as $values ) :   
                    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                        if( isset( $values['add-to-wishlist'] ) && is_numeric( $values['add-to-wishlist'] ) ) {
                            $values['prod_id'] = $values['add-to-wishlist'];
                            $values['ID'] = $values['add-to-wishlist'];
                        } else {
                            $values['prod_id'] = $values['product_id'];
                            $values['ID'] = $values['product_id'];
                        }
                    }

                    $product_obj = get_product( $values['prod_id'] );

                    if( $product_obj !== false && $product_obj->exists() ) : ?>
                    <tr id="yith-wcwl-row-<?php echo $values['ID'] ?>">
                        <td class="product-thumbnail">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product', $values['prod_id'] ) ) ) ?>">
                                <?php echo $product_obj->get_image() ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-name">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product', $values['prod_id'] ) ) ) ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cartproduct_obj_title', $product_obj->get_title(), $product_obj ) ?></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-price">
                            <?php
                            if( get_option( 'woocommerce_display_cart_prices_excluding_tax' ) == 'yes' )
                                { echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price_html', woocommerce_price( $product_obj->get_price_excluding_tax() ), $values, '' ); }
                            else
                                { echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price_html', woocommerce_price( $product_obj->get_price() ), $values, '' ); }    
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-stock-status">
                            <?php
                            $availability = $product_obj->get_availability();
                            $stock_status = $availability['class'];

                            if( $stock_status == 'out-of-stock' ) {
                                $stock_status = "Out";
                                echo '<span class="wishlist-out-of-stock">' . __( 'Out of Stock', 'Maxshop' ) . '</span>';   
                            } else {
                                $stock_status = "In";
                                echo '<span class="wishlist-in-stock">' . __( 'In Stock', 'Maxshop' ) . '</span>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-add-to-cart">
                            <?php echo YITH_WCWL_UI::add_to_cart_button( $values['prod_id'], $availability['class'] ) ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-remove"><div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="remove_item_from_wishlist( '<?php echo esc_url( $yith_wcwl->get_remove_url( $values['ID'] ) )?>', 'yith-wcwl-row-<?php echo $values['ID'] ?>');" class="remove" title="<?php _e( 'Remove this product', 'Maxshop' ) ?>">&times;</a></td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            else: ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" class="wishlist-empty"><?php _e( 'No products were added to the wishlist', 'Maxshop' ) ?></td>
                </tr>       
            <?php
            endif;

            if( isset( $page_links ) ) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><?php echo $page_links ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endif ?>
        </tbody>
     </table>
     <?php
     do_action( 'yith_wcwl_after_wishlist' );

     yith_wcwl_get_template( 'share.php' );

     do_action( 'yith_wcwl_after_wishlist_share' );
     ?>
</form>
```

style.css for wishlist:

```
/****************************WISHLIST**********************************/
.wishlist_table{margin: 20px 0;}
.wishlist_table thead tr{
    background: #f0f0f0;
    width: 100%;
}
.wishlist_table th{
    height: 72px;
    line-height: 72px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 175px;
    color: #000000;
    font: 15px 'Arial', sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.wishlist_table td{
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    font: 15px 'Arial', sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*=============================Wishlist Button===============================*/
.yith-wcwl-add-to-wishlist{
    width: 145px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.icon .yith-wcwl-add-to-wishlist{
    width: 42px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
.icon .yith-wcwl-add-to-wishlist img{
    display: none !important;
}
.icon .yith-wcwl-add-to-wishlist span{
    font-size: 9px;
}
.icon div.clear{
    display: none;
}
.icon .yith-wcwl-wishlistexistsbrowse, .icon .yith-wcwl-wishlistaddedbrowse{
    font-size: 8px;
    height: 21px;
}
.icon .yith-wcwl-wishlistexistsbrowse span, .icon .yith-wcwl-wishlistaddedbrowse span{
    display: none;
}
#selectpage{display:none}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;empty-cells:show;border:1px solid #cbcbcb}
table caption{color:#000;font:italic 85%/1 arial,sans-serif;padding:1em 0;text-align:center}
table td,
table th{border-left:1px solid #cbcbcb;border-width:0 0 0 1px;font-size:inherit;margin:0;overflow:visible;padding:6px 12px}
table td:first-child,table th:first-child{border-left-width:0}
table thead{background:#e0e0e0;color:#000;text-align:left;vertical-align:bottom}
table td{background-color:transparent}
.table-odd td{background-color:#f2f2f2}
.table-striped tr:nth-child(2n-1) td{background-color:#f2f2f2}
.table-bordered td{border-bottom:1px solid #cbcbcb}
.table-bordered tbody>tr:last-child td,
.table-horizontal tbody>tr:last-child td{border-bottom-width:0}
.table-horizontal td,
.table-horizontal th{border-width:0 0 1px;border-bottom:1px solid #cbcbcb}
.table-horizontal tbody>tr:last-child td{border-bottom-width:0}
.top-spacing{margin-top:40px !important; margin-bottom:10px}

.toggle-trigger {
    background: #fff url("images/plus.png") 90% center no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#333;
    transition: all 0.17s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.17s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.17s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.17s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle-trigger.open {
    color:#fff;
    background: #6a6a6a url("images/minas.png") 90% center no-repeat
}

.toggle-container {
    padding: 12px 22px;
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-top: none;
}
.container{max-width:100% !important}
.nav-tabs li, .work_slide li{list-style:none !important; margin-left:0 !Important; line-height:1.3}
.btn [class^="icon-"], .btn [class*=" icon-"]{margin-right:6px !Important}
strong {font-weight:bold}
em {font-style:italic}
.flex-video iframe, ifame{max-width:100% !important; }
.woocommerce li {list-style: none !important;margin-left:0}
.shopping-cart .title li, .shopping-cart ul li{margin-left:0 !important}
.showlogin {}
/*::-moz-selection { background: #f71919; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #f71919; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }*/
#wc-sorting {margin:-58px 0 40px 16px}
.product figure {border:1px solid #fff; border-bottom:none}
.product figure {border:1px solid #fff; border-bottom:none}
.related.products figure, .related.products figure > a {width:100% !important; height:auto !important} 
.related.products h2 {margin-bottom:12px}
.related.products li{border-bottom:none !important}
.sort-select {margin:-58px 0 38px 10px;display: none;}
.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {left: 150px; top:50px}


.single-product-right{ margin-left:10px}
.product-left .images {width:auto !Important}
.thumbnails a {margin-bottom:10px}
.product-detail .compare.big-button{margin-top:37px}
.no-shadow:hover{box-shadow:none !important}
.single-product .yith-wcwl-add-to-wishlist{float:left; width:124px}
.single-product a.compare {width:40px; float:left; margin-top:10px}
.single-product .product-detail div.clear {display:none}
```

and to enable **Buynow** Button on both Product catalogue page and Single Product page, i do not find any style code, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

The disparation of the buy button is really common issue.

I don't think that the wishlist plugin has something to see with this bug.

You can do the following steps to figure out :

1) Desactive any cache plugin, and try to access throught an other navigator or in private navigation mode.

Then

2) Has your product a price?

3) Is he in stock?

Those steps should show you any error in your product's config.

If you prefer to go right in code, take the product type (usually variable or simple)
Then go on your project on the file `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/{product_type}.php` or `/wp-content/themes/{your_theme}/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/{product_type}.php` if the second one exists.

And take out the different verifications, til the button appears.

Don't forget to revert your modifications if you edited the plugin's folder.

After that if you have see nothing, desactive your plugins and re-active them 1 by 1 (obviously woocommerce in first).

Btw, which plugins are you using?

Hope it's gonna help you

Comment: i am using "woocommerce" plugin

Comment: You should at least have the wishlis plugin, no?

Comment: I do not have a plugin for wishlist, i was assuming it comes with woocommerce and the theme. If you see the code which i have pasted, it has everything required for wishlist.. but the button does not showup..

Comment: Is WP_DEBUG set to true? According to https://github.com/wp-plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/blob/master/includes/class.yith-wcwl-ui.php it seems that you call a deprecated function, maybe you can have some debug help with wp_debug